# L^p space inequality

Tags: inequality

It's possible that this has already been answered, since I've seen this on another site.  Let $a,b,c,d$ be positive functions.  Is it true for all $p>1,$ that $\frac{||a+b||_p}{||c+d||_p} \leq  \max{\{\frac{||a||_p}{||c||_p}, \frac{||b||_p}{||d||_p}}\}?$

Answer (score 2):

This fails for all $p>1$. On the real line, let $a=b=c=\chi_{[0,1]}$ and $d=\chi_{[1,2]}$. All of these have $L^p$ norm $1$. But  $$\|a+b\|_{p}=2>2^{1/p} =\|c+d\|_p$$

If you want  strictly positive functions, add a tiny multiple of $\exp(-x^2)$.